# Why is Recent Documents always empty?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, documents

The Recent Documents section in my start menu is always empty, even if I have recently opened a lot of documents.  Is there some setting in Windows XP to make it work again?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the Start button and choose Properties.

Click Customize > Advanced, select "List my most recently opened documents" under "Recent documents," and click OK twice.

To show Recent Items on the Start menu in Vista, right-click the Start button, choose Properties, click the Start Menu tab, select "Store and display a list of recently opened files," and click OK

[Source](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13880_3-9953244-68.html)

Comment: This does not work. It is already enabled. I think something else may be forcing the list to be empty, or preventing items being added to it.

Comment: I also had a look in the registry and checked that the values of NoRecentDocsHistory==0 and MaxRecentDocs==16

Comment: If you're using a utility such as CCleaner or similar, than the list gets clean every time it runs. On my machine, CCleaner runs every time I empty my trash can - I don't really like those "recent" lists anyway.

Comment: I don't have CCleaner, or anything similar, installed that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled it using a utility such as TweakUI?

Check the Group Policy. Menu>>Run, type gpedit.msc, look in User Configuration>>Administrative Templates, and double click on "Clear History of recently opened documents on exit". check the "Disabled" radio button.

Comment: No. I don't have TweakUI installed.